# Redis transaction and watch command

Tags: redis, transactions

As i want to use transaction in redis. I have read documentation of redis transaction and found below.

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

but my question is if redis transaction is executed sequentially and atomic then can't we achieve above same behavior with below statements?

```
MULTI
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**, you CANNOT achieve that.

With `MULTI` and `EXEC`, you can run multiple commands atomically on the **server side**, and get all replies of these commands after `EXEC` returns.

In your case, `val = val + 1` has to be run on the **client side**, and it CANNOT be a part of the `MULTI` commands. Also, before `EXEC` returns, you CANNOT get the reply of `val = GET mykey`. So you CANNOT increase `val` before `SET mykey val`. Instead you have to run `GET` command outside `MULTI`, and use `WATCH` command to ensure the key haven't changed before when you update it.

Another solution to achieve your goal, i.e. make `val = val + 1` run on the **server side**: you can use [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval). Lua scripting is a replacement of `MULTI` and `EXEC` commands, and it runs atomically on the server side. In fact, it's [a better solution to achieve transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#redis-scripting-and-transactions).